# Remove angularjs route with yeoman

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

with Yeoman I can add a route and the controller with

```
yo angular:route myroute
```

is there a way to remove route and controller with Yeoman?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I faced a similar need to remove controller ... but from the docs I came to know that there does not seem to exist an api for deleting .

refer : https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

But to help you out for the time being I will tell what I did ....
From the docs I know which are the files created for each command .
so delete those files alone to get rid of the files produces by the yeoman operation .

for example

```
yo angular:route myroute
```

creates 3 files

```
1)    app/scripts/controllers/myroute.js              (controller)

2)    app/views/myroute.html                          (view)

3)    app/test/spec/controllers/myroute.js            (testing the controller)
```

so delete these three files alone .

for others namely

```
yo angular:controller user                app/scripts/controllers/user.js

yo angular:directive myDirective          app/scripts/directives/myDirective.js

yo angular:filter myFilter                app/scripts/filters/myFilter.js

yo angular:view user                      app/views/user.html

yo angular:service myService              app/scripts/services/myService.js

yo angular:decorator serviceName          app/scripts/decorators/serviceNameDecorator.js

yo angular:controller user --coffee       app/scripts/controller/user.coffee
```

Note : also don't forget to delete the test files inside app/test/spec which are for testing

**How can we confirm that the feature may not exists ?**

from source code for example for controller

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/controller/index.js

The api has only Generator.prototype.createControllerFiles 
so nothing for removeControllerFiles 
so we should be correct in saying that the feature doesn't exist at present .

Comment: Don't forget to delete the routes from the application's main module (`app/scripts/app.js`) too.

Comment: Adding to what @disrvptor, also remove the reference to the controller in `index.html`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but rather what files get created and where to find them.

Comment: @MaxFelker I have mentioned that "but from the docs I came to know that there does not seem to exist an api for deleting ." .. so this is the answer ... that which follows is the suggestion to get around the problem. This answer does not deserve a negative vote as far as I know ...

Answer (score 2):

## There is no API for deleting

*Like the answer above mentions you will have to delete in various places.*

**Main Location**

```
1)    app/scripts/controllers/myroute.js              (controller)

2)    app/views/myroute.html                          (view)

3)    app/test/spec/controllers/myroute.js            (testing the controller)
```

**Bonus locations**

```
4) app/scripts/app.js       (delete from app controller)
5)test/spec/controllers/myroute.js   (testing the controller) mine was outside the app dirtectory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git, this can easily be accomplished by using the clean tool:

```
git clean -f
```

The above will remove all untrack files in your working branch. In the case that yo modifies tracked files, you can just do the following:

```
git checkout file1/ file2
```

Or all of them

```
git checkout .
```